# Why await promise doesn't return all items

Tags: sql, node.js

I am using an await on promise mechanism with nodejs to get a list of rows from the database filtering on dates with between. I don't get any results, in other words the `xlsTz` array doesn't get filled. I get an empty array but I am pretty sure that there are elements to be returned after performing SQL query directly.

The thing that is more confusing, is that if i write exact dateStart and dateEnd given in my database, I get an array with only one item which I presume is last given element in the list I wished to get.

```
app.get('/getpackages/:dateStart/:dateEnd/:limit', async (req, res) => {
  var xlsTz = []

  const promiseQuery = (sql, dateStart, dateEnd, limit) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, rej)=> {
      db.query(sql, [dateStart,dateEnd,limit], function (err, results) {
        if (err) rej(err);
        resolve(results)
      });
    })
  }

  const sql = 'SELECT * FROM collection WHERE XlFile != "" AND Start BETWEEN ? AND ? LIMIT ?';

  const dateStart = req.params.dateStart;
  const dateEnd = req.params.dateStart;
  const limit = Number(req.params.limit);
  
  const results = await promiseQuery(sql, dateStart, dateEnd, limit)
  for (const counter in results) {  
    
    xlsTz.push(results[counter].XlsSourceFile);
  }

  console.log(xlsTz)

  res.send('Posts fetched...');

});
```

Can anyone help? Any ideas would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are using `res` twice one on the  router and another inside `promiseQuery`

Comment: thank you for responding. I modified the code but still the same result

Comment: can you please console.log the limit value

Comment: I think i understand what do you mean. the limit value will be specified in the path. Something like this: ```http://localhost:3000/getpackages/2016-02-16%2010:21:10/2016-02-16%2012:34:28/100```. In this case it will be 100

Comment: const limit = Number(req.params.limit);
log the value of this veraible

Comment: I did log it and it's 100.

Comment: dateStart, dateEnd are both type `date`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244368/discussion-between-sffgsfgs-and-naor-tedgi).